# Not able to get JWT token from Twitter Login with NextAuth

Tags: next.js, twitter, jwt, next-auth

I am using NextAuth for Twitter Login v2 APIs.

```js
  providers: [
    TwitterProvider({
      clientId: process.env.TWITTER_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET,
      version: "2.0",
    }),
  ],

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
      console.log(token, user, account);
      if (account) {
        token[account.provider] = {
          accessToken: account.oauth_token,
          refreshToken: account.oauth_token_secret,
        };
      }

      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      console.log(session);
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.user.id = token.id;

      return session;
    },
  },

  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
```

I am able to get userEmail, Name, and Image URL in session, but when trying to get a token in `jwt()`, It's not even going to that callback for jwt.

My end goal is to get Twitter username and Twitter follower count. but doesn't seem to be returning jwt token.

I am not sure what I am missing here, would appreciate any help I could get.

Thanks!